# How to plot multiple CSV files in a folder using python

Tags: python, pandas, csv, matplotlib, plot

Let's say I have multiple CSV files which all have their x and y coordinates start from row 15 in their own columns of 1 and 2.
I just want to run through all the CSV files in a folder running this script and just plotting x and y.

My idea so far is using glob in the current directory and importing panda so that I may be able to use ".read_csv".

However, I'm not too sure on how to set up the for loop which will be required to run through all the .csv files

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
headers = ['x', 'y']
df = pd.read_csv('C:\Users\User1\Downloads\DataLog.CSV',names=headers)
print (df)

# plot
plt.plot(x,y)
plt.show()
```

That's what I have so far just to get it working on a single file.
However, running this yields an error.

(unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape

Comment: Hello! The idea seems correct. Try to implement it, and come back if you have an error, showing your code and the error traceback. Stackoverflow is not a free coding service: as it is, this question is too broad.

Comment: Thank you, I updated with the code I've been tampering around with.

Answer (score 1):

This is very unspecific, so I can only give you a general example of how I usually do it and you'll have to figure out the errors occuring from your specific case yourself.

```py
from glob import glob
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

All_files = glob('*.csv')
headers = ('x','y')


for file in All_files:

    name = file.split('.csv')[0]

    df = pd.read_csv(file,
                      names=headers,
                      skiprows=15)

    x,y = df['x'], df['y']

    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(7,4))

    ax.plot(x,y)


    plt.tight_layout()
    plt.savefig(name+'.png', dpi=300, bbox='tight')
```

The unicode error occurs, because you specified your file path without a 'r' at the start. Strings in python often need to be declared as 'raw' strings so that they don't get misinterpreted. Your filepath: 
`'C\users\...'`
contains a '\u', which is interpreted as a unicode escape character. In python you either have to declare string literals with a leading '\', or put an r in front of it so:
`'C\\users\\...'`
or
`r'C\users\...'`